# Toolbar menu not appearing using navigation drawer and fragment

Tags: android, menu, fragment, toolbar, drawer

I'm using navigation drawer and toolbar. When I tried to create an option menu on the toolbar of the DrawerActivity, it was not shown. I went through a lot of online resources but still couldn't find a solution. Does anyone know why?

**menu_advance.xml**:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_edit_marker"
        android:orderInCategory="101"
        android:title="@string/menu_edit_marker"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_config_mode"
        android:orderInCategory="103"
        android:title="@string/reconfig_mode_on"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_installation_mode"
        android:orderInCategory="104"
        android:title="@string/installation_mode_on"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>

</menu>
```

**activity_drawer.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/drawer_activity_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_menu_white_24dp"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/drawer_header"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**DrawerActivity.java**:

```
    public class DrawerActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private DrawerLayout drawer_layout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_drawer);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.drawer_activity_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        drawer_layout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigation_view = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigation_view.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer_layout, toolbar,
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer_layout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
        toggle.syncState();

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new MapFragment(), "MAP FRAGMENT").commit();
            navigation_view.setCheckedItem(R.id.office_map);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_advance, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_config_mode:
                Toast.makeText(this, "config", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            ....
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

**MapFragment.java**:

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.drawer_activity_toolbar);
        ((AppCompatActivity) requireActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    ....
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        menu.clear();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_advance, menu);
        optionMenu = menu;
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }
```

**Manifest**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:dist="http://schemas.android.com/apk/distribution"
    package="com.example.vlcips">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".DrawerActivity"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <dist:module dist:instant="true" />

</manifest>
```

**SOLUTION:**

Bug found! Do not do setSupportActionBar(toolbar) again in the fragment. You just need to set it once in the activity.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to create options menu on the parent activity of MapFragment

**MapFragment.java:**

```
 @Override
public View onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_advance, menu);
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    // handle menu item clicks here
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

No need to override onCreateOptionsMenu in DrawerActivity.java.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_drawer);

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.drawer_activity_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
.....
}
```

Comment: Not what I was looking for but it gave me a new idea to solve the problem. Thank you!